# How to stop migration in Entity Framework 6 once and for all?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations, ef-database-first

I am using Entity Framework 6 with an ASP.NET MVC 5 application. I do NOT want to use code-first approach in my project.

I created a new project and never enabled migrations. I created a new class called `MyContext` which extends `DbContext` class. Here is what I have in `MyContext` constructor

```
public MyContext()
    : base(ConnectionName)
{
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
}
```

However, each time I debut the application, I see the following output in my `Debug output` screen.

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t...
```

and

```
SELECT 
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT 
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
)  AS ......
```

How can I really stop migration in my application?

Comment: Did you already deleted __MigrationHistory table from backend and Migration folder from the solution?

Comment: Do your project have any `Migrations` folder, or any `Configuration.cs` file? If yes, try deleting them.

Comment: I do not have a __MigrationHistory table. I also do not have Migrations folder or `Configuration.cs` file. These things would be created after one enables migration from the console which is something I did not do

Comment: Have you tried `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(new NullDatabaseInitializer<MyContext>()`?

Comment: Are you trying to get rid of code first or just migrations? Disabling migrations is easy as others have pointed out. Going from code first to database first is a bit more work.

Answer (score 3):

If it is true you have not `Migrations` folder, and no `Configuration.cs` file, the only thing I think you missed is the database initializer.
Even if you are disabling database initialization with `Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);`, it can be configured using the configuration file:

To disable it using configuration files, add ([source](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/turn-off-database-initialization-in-code-first.aspx)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings>    
        <add key="DatabaseInitializerForType MyNamespace.MyDbContext, MyNamespace" 
             value="Disabled" />
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

there are plenty of examples out there. The first thing you need to do is install the power tools through nuget, then if you already have a DB use the reverse engineer wizard. Also take a look at this if you are starting from scratch: [EF DB First](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj206878(v=vs.113).aspx)

this will create the correct context etc for you.

if your using .net core then take a look at this link

[.net core reverse engineer](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-using-Entity-1464feea)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the line

```
Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
```

Needs to be in a static constructor, not an instance constructor! :)

So do this:

```
static MyContext()
{
        Database.SetInitializer<MyContext>(null);
}
```